# PhoneGap iframe one finger scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app in `PhoneGap` 2.4 using `jQuery` and `jQuery Mobile`. The app has a top bar and bottom navigation bar, both of which are stationary. In the middle is where all the action happens.

The middle section is a DIV and I'm trying to load an cloud positioned `PDF` into an `iframe` inside the div. However, being as iOS is, the `PDF` and/or `iframe` won't scroll with one finger once the `PDF` is loaded in the `iframe`. I can use two fingers to scroll with, but this is not the desired result.

So my question is, how can I get the `iframe` to scroll with one finger.

Also, if it's possible, can I enable pinch zoom within the `iframe` so as to increase/decrease the size of the `PDF`? iOS only displays the `PDF` at about half the width of the iPad.

Here's the `CSS` I'm using/tried:

```
iframe {
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
zoom: 200%;
}

#display_area {
max-width: 1024px;
min-height: 558px !important;
height: 558px !important;
max-height: 558px !important;
overflow-y:scroll;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! 2 hours down and not even the slightest whisper. Another question that has the geniuses stumped.

Comment: try iScroll.js , worked pretty good in one of my project where youtube video is loaded in iframe.